# Is message consumption from AWS SQS atomic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I know SQS has concept of Timeout visibility to set a timeperiod in which a message can not be consumed.

But, what if I have multiple consumers trying to read SQS at a time?

Is there a chance more than one consumer receive the same message?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I think FIFO should address my use-case.